# Segmentation fault using linux command lines in c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

When I run the command line ./hello.out, the core is dumped. Can someone tell me what I am missing.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int counter = 1, sum = 0,x;
x= atoi(argv[1]);
if (x<0)
{cout << "Error\n"; exit(1);}
if (argc !=2)
{cout << "Error\n"; exit(1);}

while (counter <= x)
    {
            cout << counter << endl;
            sum = sum + counter;
            ++counter;
    }
cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `argv[1]` does not exist, the program will crash since you're attempting to read a value that does not exist. You need to call it with at least one parameter, or do some error checking. For example: `./hello.out 5`

For example, you could put this on the line before you attempt to call `atoi(n)`:

`if (argc < 2) return -1;`

Comment: And there is never any excuse for using atoi().

Comment: We prefer the term "Undefined Behaviour" to "Crash" because it won't always crash. It may screw up in a much quieter, more insidious fashion that no one notices before it's too late.

Comment: My apologies, undefined behavior is of course the appropriate term here. Thank you!

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* - an understanding of [what the arguments to `main()` mean](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function), and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to access elements of `argv` that don't exist, and thus you are accessing memory that your program doesn't control. When you do this the kernel will immediately kill your program. You're checking the value of `argc`, which is the right thing to do, but you're doing it after you've accessed `argv`. You just need to perform that check before accessing `argv`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;      

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int counter = 1, sum = 0,x;

    if (argc !=2) argv    // <-- Make sure there are two elements before indexing into
    {
        cout << "Error\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    x = atoi(argv[1]);    // <-- You should study and use 'std::stoi' instead
    if ( x < 0 )      
    {
        cout << "Error\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    while (counter <= x)
    {
        cout << counter << endl;
        sum = sum + counter;
        ++counter;
    }
    cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well....on line 6 you access argv[1] yet you have not passed any paraeters...so argv[1] could point anywhere